# Why local and global installations of Composer rolls back to a different version?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have both local (per project -- executed by `php composer.phar`) and global (executed by `composer`) versions installed on my Windows. Today I updated both and noticed weird results of this update.

For global installation:

```
$ composer self-update
Updating to version 92faf1c7a83a73794fb914a990be435e1df373ca.
    Downloading: 100%
Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 42bfe9c56adb555cc08e9ce
2d32f6763ff75ae5d
```

For local one:

```
$ php composer.phar self-update
Updating to version 92faf1c7a83a73794fb914a990be435e1df373ca.
    Downloading: 100%
Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 943107cfe717a74aa791f57
b87fa514c88582b0d
```

Both installations were updated to newest (`92faf1c7a83a73794fb914a990be435e1df373ca`) version, but **both showed different version number they'll be rolled back to**. Why? What am I missing?

In addition, it turned out, that newest version (latest snapshot) of Composer has some bugs. Running both `composer update` or `php composer.phar update` throws a bunch of notices like that:

```
Deprecation Notice: Composer\Package\Version\VersionParser::parseLinks is deprec ated. Use \Composer\Package\Loader\ArrayLoader::parseLinks() instead in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionParser.php:226
```

Thus, I decided to roll back both installations. And, as I was "promised", both installations were rolled back to **a different previous versions**.

For global installation:

```
$ composer self-update --rollback
Rolling back to version 2015-07-12_15-39-36-42bfe9c.
```

And for local one:

```
$ php composer.phar self-update --rollback
Rolling back to version 2015-06-26_13-40-26-943107c.
```

This way, the initial question returns. Why both my installations always updates to the same version (newest one), but rolls back to a different one?

Comment: well, because you had 2 different versions? The update fetches the latest (not the first subsequent version of the one you have), which is of course the same, but rollbacks to what it was before, so a different version

Comment: Had you done the previous `self-update` on the same day?

Comment: @DamienPirsy Sounds like a good answer to my question. Why just comment. [Is there any way to rollback to or install precisely selected snapshot](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31424186/1469208) or is this feature  limited to "official" versions only?

Comment: @MarkBaker No, of course not. They were made in long period of time, since I mostly use global version and local one very rarely. I assume, that doing `self-update` on both version in the same day would obviously result in having both installations in the same version / snapshot, right?

Comment: Both "updated" versions will have the same snapshot; but you're not rolling back to that version; you're rolling back to the "previous" version.... and if the previous version on each box had been created on different dates from different snapshots, then those will be the versions that you rollback to

Comment: It looks like composer bag. Issue already created:
https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4260

Answer (score 0):

As per [Damien Pirsy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594509/damien-pirsy)'s and [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker)'s comments, it is just the nature of Composer.

When using rollback mechanism, Composer rolls itself back to the previous version, that was installed on that particular machine (or in that particular place, since we're talking about Composer's local and global installations). When some installation wasn't updated for a longer period of time, it may happen, that it simply "skipped" certain versions or snapshots in between.

For example, an installation updated in May and then again in June, will be rolled back to May's version even though, there were certain versions / snapshots in between, during July.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

> php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.1"
>   or
>   composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.1"