# Can I install Composer in selected snapshot or only in "official" version

Tags: php, composer-php

It turned out, that [both my global and local installations of Composer are in different snapshot versions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424015/1469208) -- global is `2015-07-12_15-39-36-42bfe9c` and local in `2015-06-26_13-40-26-943107c`. Both updates to newest version / snapshot, but always rolls back to previous one in installation history, not to previous one in release history (i.e. not to the one before latest snapshot, not to the same one).

Is there any way, I can roll back each installation of Composer to a specific snapshot? To have both installations in the same version / snapshot, but not the newest one ([which has some bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424015/1469208))?

I [know](https://getcomposer.org/download/), that I can install Composer in any version, I want, using `--version` switch. But, this covers only an official versions, where the latest one before latest snapshot is `1.0.0-alpha10 (2015-04-14)`, that is far before versions, to which my current installations rolls back.

Answer (score 0):

As for local installations of Composer, this is of course possible and only requires copying `composer.phar` file, in selected version, over all projects, that are using local installation of Composer. This way, all of them will have local Composer in the very same version / snapshot.

As for global installation, this seems to be impossible.